# burninate 'reader' tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[reader](/questions/tagged/reader) seems like a meaningless keyword-type tag that has no single meaning. There are 352 questions, no tag wiki, 3 followers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: burninated]

I first retagged all of the obvious Google Reader / Adobe Reader questions to [google-reader](/questions/tagged/google-reader) and [adobe-reader](/questions/tagged/adobe-reader) respectively. The remaining 300 or so just had the tag removed completely.